# Какой программой можно заменить Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Какой программой можно заменить Android Studio?
P.s.У меня Windows XP и мне не хочется обновлять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**IntelliJ IDEA**](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/) - поддерживает наиболее популярные серверные и интерфейсные платформы. В том числе **Android**.

**AndroidStudio** основан на ней. И выглядит также..

---

Из описания:

> IntelliJ IDEA provides the same coding assistance and integrated toolset for developing Android applications as Android Studio, the official IDE for Android application development from Google.

Причем эта опция есть даже в бесплатной версии **Community Edition**.

---

Поддерживаемые операционные системы:

- Microsoft Windows 10/8/7/Vista/2003/XP (32 or 64 bit)
- macOS 10.8 or later (only 64-bit systems are supported)
- OS Linux (note that a 32-bit JDK is not bundled, so a 64-bit system is recommended); KDE, Gnome or Unity DE desktop

---

[Установка и настройка IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/install-and-set-up-intellij-idea.html)

Answer (score 0):

Решение программировать для системы Android из Windows XP выглядит очень странно.

1. Поддержка системы XP уже давно прекратилась.
2. Вы сможете программировать только для старых версий Android
3. Вы не обновите эмуляторы Anndroid, которые были с багами и много еще чего.

Лучшее решение использовать систему семейства Linux для этих целей.